# Issues setting up a test case for when withdrawal fails in my Contract

Tags: contract-development, ethers.js, hardhat, unittesting

**Question Description:**
I created a contract that users can fund and only the owner of the Contract can withdraw the funds from the Contract. The Contract is below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

// Imports
import "./PriceConverter.sol";

// Error
error FundMeEth__notOwner();
error FundMeEth__notEnoughFund();
error FundMeEth__notAvailable();
error FundMeEth__withdrawFailed();
error FundMeEth__notEnoughWithdrawFund();
error FundMeEth__reentrantCallDetected();

/**
    @title A contract for funding and withdrawing Ethereum from a contract.
    @author Eyang, Daniel Eyoh
    @notice Only owner is allowed to withdraw money from the contract.
    @dev This implements pricefeeds to generate ethereum current market value.
 */
contract FundMeEth {
    /* Type Declaration */
    using PriceConverter for uint256;
    enum FundMeEthState { // set the state of the contract.
        OPEN,
        PENDING
    }

    /* State Variables */
    < ------ State variables declaration ------>

    // Events
    event UserFunded(address indexed funder, uint256 amount);
    event WithdrawalSuccessful(address indexed recipient, uint256 beforeAmount, uint256 afterAmount);
    event WithdrawalFailed(address indexed recipient, uint256 amount);

    /* Modifiers */
    // using a modifier for authentication of the withdraw function, i.e only the owner of the contract can withdraw
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if(msg.sender != i_owner) {
            revert FundMeEth__notOwner();
        }
        _; // this means after verification is done. then run the code below in the function
    }

    /* Constructor */
    constructor(address priceFeedAddress) {
    <--- constructor ----->
    }

    /* receive and callback */
    // This handles when a user sends fund to the contract without calling the fund function.
    receive() external payable {
        fund();
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        fund();
    }

    /* public function */
    /**
        @notice Funds the Contract
        @dev 
    */
    function fund() public payable {
    <--- fund codes ----->
    }

    /**
        @notice doWithdraw method, only the contract Owner makes this request successful.
        @dev
    */
    function doWithdraw() internal onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        // Acquire the reentrancy lock
        if (locked) {
            revert FundMeEth__reentrantCallDetected();
        }
        locked = true;

        // Check if there is any balance left in the contract
        if (address(this).balance <= 0) {
            revert FundMeEth__notEnoughWithdrawFund();
        }

        // Transfer the balance to the owner
        uint256 balanceBeforeTransfer = address(this).balance;
        if (!payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance)) {
            emit WithdrawalFailed(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
            return false;
        }

        // Emit an event to signal successful withdrawal
        emit WithdrawalSuccessful(msg.sender, balanceBeforeTransfer, address(this).balance);

        // Reset state variables after successful transfer
        resetStateVariables();

        // Release the reentrancy lock
        locked = false;

        return true;
    }

    /**
        @notice reset the state variables after a successful withdrawal
        @dev
    */
    function resetStateVariables() private {
     < --- reset codes ----->
    }

    /**
        @notice withdraw method, calls the doWithdraw method.
        @dev
    */
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        // disable funding
        s_fundState = FundMeEthState.PENDING;

        // Call the doWithdraw method and propagate its result
        bool success = doWithdraw();

        // Update state based on the outcome of doWithdraw
        if (success) {
            s_fundState = FundMeEthState.OPEN;
        } else {
            // set state to Open
            s_fundState = FundMeEthState.OPEN;
            // Revert withdrawal due to failure in doWithdraw
            revert FundMeEth__withdrawFailed();
        }
    }

    /* view */
    < ---- setters and getters functions below ----> 
}
```

While writing the test I encountered an issue writing test for the doWithdraw function where the withdraw process fails and emits the WithdrawalFailed event.

```
        if (!payable(msg.sender).send(address(this).balance)) {
            emit WithdrawalFailed(msg.sender, address(this).balance);
            return false;
        }
```

I'm working with hardhat, chai, mocha, and current ethers@6.10.0. Please can anyhow help me with writing a test that satisfies that condition?

**Method tried:**
I tried creating a new Contract called FailingContract that fails whenever called, and I also updated to FundMeEth contract to include a setter function that changed the Owner of the Contract. Codes below:

```
Failing Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract FailingContract {
    // Fallback function that always reverts
    fallback() external payable {
        revert("Fallback function intentionally reverts");
    }
}
```

Then the update made to the FundMeEth Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

// ... other imports ...

contract FundMeEth {
    // address private immutable i_owner;
    address private i_owner; // immutability removed only for testing (so the owner can be changed)
    // ... existing code ...

    // Add a function to set the owner for testing purposes
    function setOwner(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        i_owner = newOwner;
    }

    // ... rest of the contract ...
}
```

My test code:

```
describe('FundMeEth Contract', async () => {
    let fundMeEth;
    let deployer;
    let user;
    let mockV3Aggregator;
    let connectedFundMeEth;
    let failingContract;
    const sendValue = ethers.parseEther("0.1");

    beforeEach(async () => {
        // Get deployer and user
        [deployer, user] = await ethers.getSigners();
        // Deploy all contract
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]);

        // Get the contract factory
        const fundMeEthFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("FundMeEth");
        // Attach the deployed contract instance
        fundMeEth = fundMeEthFactory.attach(
            (await deployments.get("FundMeEth")).address
        );

        // Connect the contract to another instance
        connectedFundMeEth = fundMeEth.connect(user);

        // Get the contract factory
        const failingContractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("FundMeEth");
        // Attach the deployed contract instance
        failingContract = failingContractFactory.attach(
            (await deployments.get("FailingContract")).address
        );

        // Get the contract factory for MockV3Aggregator
        const mockV3AggregatorFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MockV3Aggregator");
        // Attach the deployed MockV3Aggregator contract instance
        mockV3Aggregator = mockV3AggregatorFactory.attach(
            (await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")).address
        );
    });

    < ---- other existing test --->
    describe('doWithdraw function', async () => {  // assuming the doWithdraw function is extternal
        it('should emit WithdrawalFailed event when the send function fails', async () => {
            // Fund the contract
            await fundMeEth.fund({ value: sendValue });
    
    
            // Change the owner of the FundMeEth contract to the failing contract's address
            await fundMeEth.setOwner(failingContract.target);  // failingContract.target === failingContract.address

    
            // Try to withdraw
            const tx = await fundMeEth.doWithdraw();
    
            // Check that the WithdrawalFailed event was emitted
            await expect(tx)
                .to.emit(fundMeEth, 'WithdrawalFailed')
                .withArgs(failingContract.target, sendValue);
    
            // Check that the contract's balance is still intact
            const contractBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(fundMeEth.target);
            expect(contractBalance).to.equal(sendValue);
        });
    });
});
```

But the error I get from the test indicates that the withdrawal was successful without emitting any event which indicates that the process didn't fail. Please I need help on this.

Comment: Which error have you been getting? The culprit may be with the local network you're using for testing. See (https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomicfoundation-hardhat-ethers#events-are-not-being-emitted)

Comment: The test fails with an Error showing that it didn't emit what it was meant to (WithdrawalFailed). So this means that my attempt to create a failed withdrawal process didn't work, making the withdrawal successful (emitting WithdrawalSuccess). I want to create a test scenario when the withdrawal process fails so I will know what to handle or see what is returned